# How to access an array of objects from another class

Tags: c#, oop

I'm trying to loop through an array of objects and print their properties from a different class.

My main class is

```
class Program
    {

        static void Main()
        {
            //This to be change to relative path
            string Path = @"C:\Users\";
            string[] lines = { }; ;

            //Reading file
            if (File.Exists(Path))
            {
                lines = File.ReadAllLines(Path);
                StudentReport.ReadStudents(lines);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The file does't exist");
            }

            //Printing Students
            PrintStudent.Print(lines.Length);
        }
    }
```

I'm using this code to declare the array

```
public class StudentReport
    {
        public static void ReadStudents(string[] Lines)
        {
            //declare an array with the number of students
            Student[] studentArray = new Student[Lines.Length];
            int StudentCounter = 0;

            foreach (string Line in Lines)
            {

                String[] Student = Line.Split(',');

                //Calculating values
                string ID = Student[0].PadLeft(10, '0');
                string name = Student[1];

                //Initialize the object
                studentArray[StudentCounter] = new Student
                {
                    FullName = name,
                    ID = ID,
                };

                StudentCounter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

And I'm using this class to construct my student object

```
class Student
    {
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        public string ID { get; set; }
    }
```

To output the student object properties, I made another class. The problem is that I couldn't access the value of the objects array from my new class.

The class I made for outputting purposes is the following, but I cannot get the values. The error is 'Student does not contain a definition for student array

```
public class PrintStudent
    {
        public static void Print(int StudentCounter)
        {

            for(int i = 0; i > StudentCounter; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(Student.studentArray[i].FullName);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: After you create the array in `ReadStudents` you should return it to the caller of that method. By not doing that you are discarding the work that method accomplished. The `Print` method should be called by something and instead of a counter it should probably have the Student instance passed to it but now we are at speculation and mater of opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is `Student does not contain a definition for studentArray`. This is because your `Student` class does not have `studentArray`, only the properties `FullName` and `ID`.  So accessing `Student.studentArray[i]` doesn't make sense.

Probably what you want is for ReadStudents to return the studentArray so it doesn't go out of scope by changing the method signature to return the Student[], and calling return studentArray at the end.

Then, you can pass your studentArray to your `PrintStudent.Print` method in the parameters.

By the way, the `for(int i = 0; i > StudentCounter; i++)` has a wrong < and will never run (lines.Length which is the StudentCounter will always be >= 0)

You can use `studentArray.Length`, or a foreach loop to iterate over this array, rather than pass the StudentCounter.

Comment: I tried to return the array by adding
``` public static Student[] ReadStudents(string[] Lines) ```
are returning the value to
``` Stuedents = StudentReport.ReadStudents(lines); ``` 
But I still get an error of can't implicitly convert type to string[]

Comment: @AnasBaheh are you returning the `studentArray` or `Lines`, using the [return keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/return)? I don't know without seeing your updated code.